# Java: creatingQuery returns null

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am trying to return the id of the user, using his email, so I have a method in my dao class that is suppose to return the id of the user and this method takes an email as a parameter:

```
public int trouverUtil( String email ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Query req = em.createQuery("select u.id_utilisateur from Utilisateur u where u.mail = :x");
    req.setParameter("x",email);
    return  req.getFirstResult();
}
```

But when I execute the application, and I try to print the result of the method `trouverUtil` I get '0'. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method `getFirstResult()` does not return an id
take a look here [getFirstResult()](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/Query/getFirstResult)

to returne an id you must call `req.getResultList()`

```
List<Long> ids = req.getResultList();
return ids.get(0);
```